# Visualising changed/added/removed Git lines in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there analog of vim-gitgutter for IntelliJ IDEA?

You can see in the screenshot how vim-gitgutter marks changed/added/removed lines using symbols '~', '+' and '-'. I would like to get something like that in IDEA.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like this? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html#2 (check line status in editor)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set up version control for your project. You can do that in "File" -> "Settings..." -> "Version control" -> then set "VCS" to "Git" (or any other supported VCS). Once you have done that, the editor shows color bands for changed lines (green for added, blue for changed, red for removed). See also the [IntelliJ manual page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html#2).

Answer (score 7):

If the gutter marks are missing this could be caused by plugins. I was able to get them back by enabling in settings (in Webstorm):

Editor > General > Gutter (bottom) > Highlight modified lines in gutter

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the option I was looking for. I don't know how it got unchecked at some point (maybe when I installed a them and then removed it).

Answer (score 1):

Mine disappeared unexpectedly, some kind of bug perhaps. I was able to fix 
 "File" -> "Settings..." -> "Version control" -> then set "VCS" to "None" and then toggled back to "Git". Voila, the git gutter markers appeared again.

Comment: Faced with the same bug on Android Studio 2020.3.1 (Mac OS)